# HTTP 500 error after switching from developer mode to production mode

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, http-error-500, developer-mode, production-mode

After switching to production mode, website is giving http 500 error. Admin side is opening but no pictures. What should i do?

Comment: have you looked at the server log to see why the 500 is happening?

Comment: @PhilippSander i've looked for apache logs and haven't find out what's wrong but i've tried so many combinations and finally found something, finally. i've disabled css and js merging before switching. I am using cloudflare and disabled from there, too. Then, i have deployed static content specific for all languages. It worked. Now, i'll give it a try to enable rocket loader and the other compressing things step by step and see if it is working or not.